# What should i do to sent and store data from 8051 microcontroller to a pc?

Tags: serial-port, 8051

How to transfer and store data from a 8051 microcontroller to a pc via rs232/usb cable?

I expect, what I enter should be stored in a pc.
Lcd and keyboard are interfaced to the 8051.The data I enter displayed on the lcd the same should be stored in the pc. What should i do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The first thing to do is to take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and the second thing is to read "[ask]". The third thing to do is to [edit] your question and add details how concretely we can help you. What is your specific hardware, does it exist already? What do you want to do with the entered keys? What should be displayed on the LCD? Which software on the PC should "talk" to your 8051? See, these requirements are only in your hand...